# Rails adds an extra 'command' object to my POST params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 4.1 is adding a strange object to my POST parameters, which is a duplicate of the data I post.

As a very basic test, I post a simple `{"msg"=>"hello word!"}` from Angular:

```
$http.post('/commands/save.json', {msg:'hello word!'}).
```

Rails gets:

```
Started POST "/commands/save.json" for ::1 at 2015-01-08 10:15:55 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ngconf_schema_migrations`.* FROM `ngconf_schema_migrations`
Processing by CommandsController#save as JSON
  Parameters: {"msg"=>"hello word!", "command"=>{"msg"=>"hello word!"}}
{
        "msg" => "hello word!",
        "controller" => "commands",
        "action" => "save",
        "format" => "json",
        "command" => {
            "msg" => "hello word!"
        }
}
  Commands Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ngconf_commands`.* FROM `ngconf_commands`
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.8ms)
```

Basically I am trying to understand where does this come from and how to stop it. I do not remember Rails 4.0 doing this.

```
        "command" => {
            "msg" => "hello word!"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is coming from [ParamsWrapper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html). You can disable this by specifying `wrap_parameters false` in the controller. If you would like to disable it application wide, edit your `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` and set the `:format` option to an empty array as per the comments. As an example

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
#
# This file contains settings for ActionController::ParamsWrapper which
# is enabled by default.

# Enable parameter wrapping for JSON. You can disable this by setting :format to an empty array.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: []
end
```